# How to save file in public storage with Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a beginner in Android / Kotlin.

I can save a .txt file in the private app directory `(/data/data/com.sky.altipro/files/AltiPro2023-08-26-14:43:08.908.log)` without any problem.

However, I did not find a way to save it in the public shared storage `location (/storage/emulated/0/Documents)`. The well know violation message comes:

```
 //  val directory = this.filesDir
            //val directory = File(this.filesDir, "AltiPro").apply { mkdirs() }
            // val directory = File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "AltiPro").apply { mkdirs() }
           // val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "AltiPro").apply { mkdirs() }
           // val directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
           val directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
           val file = File(directory,fileName)
           file.appendText("${location.time},${location.latitude},${location.longitude},$AltitudeInt\n")
```

Caused by: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/AltiPro2023-08-27-18:06:55.240.txt: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`. I tried the Manifest permissions... but since API30, this has no effect.

This file contains flight information and I would like the user to be able to download it and review it in Excel or Google Earth.

I read the Android documentation, but was not able to develop a code, since API30 I found it rather difficult and did not find any actual example on the web.

Is any simple code available for me to get me inspired?

Thanks.

Comment: `I tried the Manifest permissions... but since API30, this has no effect.` Not true. Maybe since 34. But then you did not tell which permissions you have in mind.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more information to help you: 1. Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message. 2. Please remove the commented code from your question since it only adds noise. 3. Show the version of your code that has "manifest permissions". 4. Show the result of using these permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You should let user save it in [Shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared).

Use the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent action to load the system file picker and allow the user to choose a location where to write the contents of a file. This process is similar to the one used in the "save as" dialogs that other operating systems use.

That doesn't require any permissions.

Check this out: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I believe Wear os does not support SAF. I got a a message "no app to handle this action".

Comment: @JeromeJeanneret have a look at this: 
https://medium.com/android-development-by-danylo/android-wear-shared-storage-for-smartwatch-and-the-phone-7c8777b64238

Comment: Thank! very interesting, but my idea was to avoid a companion app. I just need to send a file... frankly, this is quite surprising to see there is not easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

> > AltiPro2023-08-27-18:06:55.240.txt

File names cannot contain the forbidden character `:`.

Comment: Thanks, strangely the file name creates no issue. I am able to save in the private app folder.